# Expo Form Data send to POST API

Tags: reactjs, expo

for the first time i'm implement API in my react(expo) app. even i don't even know react as well.
I start to googling and try to do something. my code is:

```
export default function SignUp({route, navigation}) {

const [name, onChangeName] = React.useState();

const clickHandler = () => {
    fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/adhithiravi/React-Hooks-Examples/master/testAPI.json')
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
        console.log(name);
}

return (
    <ScrollView>
        <View>
            <View>
                <TextInput placeholder="Name" onChangeName={text => onChangeName(text)} />  
            </View>
            <View>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={clickHandler}>
                    <Text style={styles.signupTxt}>Sign Up</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
);
}
```

after "on press" i call an event, where i try to fetch an API. but i can't send my field value inside this event.

Comment: Please provide error messages if applicable and expand your answer with additional information.

Comment: You need to provide the field value in the name part of API right?

Answer (score -1):

You have a **typo** in the [`TextInput`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput) props change `onChangeName` -> `onChangeText`

```
// wrong
<TextInput placeholder="Name" onChangeName={text => onChangeName(text)} />

// correct
<TextInput placeholder="Name" onChangeText={text => onChangeName(text)} />
```

Comment: This might not be the full solution but I am confident that this step is a must. Please update your question with more information.